# Highcharts x-range how to show Data?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using Highcharts x-range in Angular application to show data in date range but all the codes I tryied doesn't work for me.

This is my code :

```
export class xRangeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  chartData;
  highcharts = Highcharts;

  chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: 'xrange'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
      min: Date.UTC(2010, 11, 3, 0),
      max: Date.UTC(2015, 11, 4, 0),
      tickInterval: 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {text: ''},
      categories: [],
      reversed: true
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Example',
      borderRadius: 5,
      pointWidth: 10,
      data: [
      ],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
]}

  constructor(
      @Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    // set xAxis
    const xAxis = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.chartData.length; i++) {
      const data = { x: new Date(this.chartData[i].date_start).toISOString(),
        x2: new Date(this.chartData[i].date_end).toISOString(), y: i };
      xAxis.push(data);
    }
    this.chartOptions.series[0].data = xAxis;

    // Set yAxis
    this.chartOptions.yAxis.categories = this.chartData.map(item => item.name);

  }
}
```

And those are the Data in Json file:

```
"chartData": [{
  "id": "92765478890",
  "name": "Bibi",
  "date_start": "2010-01-01",
  "date_end": "2013-02-01"
},
  {
    "id": "92765478890",
    "name": "toto",
    "date_start": "2011-08-01",
    "date_end": "2013-10-01"
  },
  {
    "id": "92765478890",
    "name": "titi",
    "date_start": "2013-03-01",
    "date_end": "2014-09-01"
  }
]
```

And this is the result :
[image]

To use Highcharts I installed

"highcharts": "^9.0.1",
"highcharts-angular": "^2.10.0",

And to use x-range chart I added in my module :

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import Exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
import xrange from 'highcharts/modules/xrange';
xrange(Highcharts);
Exporting(Highcharts);
```

I hope you can help me to find why it doesn't work !

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I should parse the date using Date.parse() so this is the code :

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.chartData.length; i++) {
   const data = { y: i, x: Date.parse(this.chartData[i].date_start),
   x2: Date.parse(this.chartData[i].date_start)};
   xAxis.push(data);
}
```